# setInterval, click something then clearInterval, and then few seconds setInterval again

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

i want to create a slider image that running uses setInterval, when i click on the thumbail, the image slider stops, but after a few seconds i want it continues to run setInterval again, i'm stuck here. I don't know how to write the code so that setInterval runs again

```
//auto animate
let counter = 0;
function imageChange() {
  bigImage.src = thumb[counter++].src;
  if(counter >= thumb.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
let gallery = setInterval(imageChange, 1000);
//click thumb stop Animate then runs again
for(t of thumb) {
  t.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    bigImage.src = e.target.src;
    clearInterval(gallery);
    //I'm stuck here :(
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pause = setTimeout(() => { gallery = setInterval(imageChange, 1000)} ,3000);
```

like this

```js
let pause;
//auto animate
let counter = 0;
function imageChange() {
  bigImage.src = thumb[counter++].src;
  if(counter >= thumb.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
let gallery = setInterval(imageChange, 1000);
//click thumb stop Animate then runs again
for(t of thumb) {
  t.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    bigImage.src = e.target.src;
    clearInterval(gallery);
    clearTimeout(pause);
    pause = setTimeout(() => { gallery = setInterval(imageChange, 1000)} ,3000);
  });
}
```

I would delegate though

```js
let pause;
//auto animate
let counter = 0;
function imageChange() {
  bigImage.src = thumb[counter++].src;
  if(counter >= thumb.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
let gallery = setInterval(imageChange, 1000);
//click thumb stop Animate then runs again
document.getElementById('thumbContainerId').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  bigImage.src = e.target.src;
  clearInterval(gallery);
  clearTimeout(pause);
  pause = setTimeout(() => { gallery = setInterval(imageChange, 1000)} ,3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot PAUSE the setInterval function, you can either STOP it (clearInterval), or let it run.

When you click on, just set isPaused as true. When close a thumbnail set isPaused as false.

```js
//auto animate
let counter = 0;
let isPaused = false;
function imageChange() {
  if(isPaused){
    return;
  }
 //Your code
}
let gallery = setInterval(imageChange, 1000);
//click thumb stop Animate then runs again
for(t of thumb) {
  t.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    bigImage.src = e.target.src;
    isPaused = true;
  });
}

function closeThumnail(){
  isPaused = false;
}
```

Comment: OP is not using the word pause. OP wants to restart after clearing but after a while. You can use a toggle like you or use setTimeout to restart as I did